# Web Workers: A solution for stutter-free Youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, youtube, web-worker

I've currently completed a web app that plays back Youtube videos. A Youtube *HTML5* video plays back super smooth (no visible lagging or glitches even when CPU is at 90+ active) while my app (which uses jQuery UI) accepts form input or achieves element manipulation (User or dynamically triggered). However, when Youtube force-feeds my app with a *Flash* video, anytime there is form entry, DOM manipulation, or cursor moving rapidly over the UI, the Flash video stutters, coughs, belches and acts in respite (regardless of CPU level. Audio is ok though) until GUI manipulation ceases.

My client-side web app is built with Javascript and jQuery 2.10 and accesses Youtube videos through Youtube's Data API v3.

**Question**: What could I do with Web Workers to make certain that UI interaction never affects video playback (and vice versa), regardless of the video format Youtube currently feeds back through its data API (version 3)?

**Question**: If Web Workers can't help me, what could I implement client-side wise (besides avoiding Youtube Flash video) to solve this dilemma?

Any sensible tips/solutions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A couple things to note here:  Web Workers cannot interact with the DOM in any way, you can pass information back via messaging, and do calculations in a separate thread but all data has to be passed via messaging with the Worker.  So Workers will not be able to help you in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure webworkers would be helpful at all with an embedded flash video ?

Comment: @WakeskaterX So accessing js scripts that do UI manipulation  -- through Web Workers -- is impossible? How about caching those scripts in Local Storage?

Comment: @koolness Yeah, the global scope is separate from the window, so you have no access to the DOM within a web worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Workers won't be too helpful here (for taking on anything UI related).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

The global scope for Web Workers is separate from the window, so you have no access to the DOM from within the worker.

You might want to consider creating a variable toggle for Loading State and only allowing GUI events if you're not currently loading.  Otherwise I'm not too sure about what you could do for the second question other than optimize the heck out of your JavaScript.

**Edit**:  As far as loading the video in the worker, you might be able to do that by making the XMLHttpRequest and getting the data, and then sending the data in chunks to the main thread once you buffer it some.  Check out this article for more info:  http://techslides.com/html5-web-workers-for-ajax-requests

Comment: Would caching those js scripts and accessing them through Local Storage be of any help?

Comment: For general use in your main scripts, anything you can cache and reference later will be helpful.  Basically you're likely going to want to just optimize your scripts as best you can.

Comment: Yeah, I gleaned over the link contents. At "Further examples" section, "Workers are mainly useful for allowing your code to perform processor-intensive calculations without blocking the user interface thread". But my prob is that my user interface thread integrity isn't the issue, it's the reverse ( Flash video ) lol.

Comment: But you need to play your video in the browser right?  You MIGHT be able to reach out and start streaming the data in the worker... It looks like a worker might be able to make the XMLHttpRequest to get the data, but then you'd have to reach out to the worker as it's getting the data and buffering it to load the data from the worker in chunks into the DOM.

Comment: Yep. Need to play within Youtube's embedded iFrame player. Starting to stream from the Worker could be it, but how about streaming a video buffered (cached) through Local Storage (or similar)?

Comment: Web Workers do not have access to the localstorage or sessionstorage, so you'd still have to do all that on the main thread which kind of defeats the point of using a web worker, that seems like WAY more processing time than just loading it.